# Are there any in-memory JDBC databases that support XA distributed transactions?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I want to use an in-memory database to test my application, but it needs to support [XA distributed transactions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/XADataSource.html). My first idea for an in-memory database was [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), but it appears not to support XA. Are there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html) supports this.

Comment: Yes, H2 supports the XA API. Please note that H2 doesn't support all XA features, but for most applications it should be OK.

Comment: Note that H2 heuristically rolls back prepared transactions when the client disconnects. See https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2347

Answer (score 1):

Both **H2 database** and **HSQLDB** support it, couldn't find any other java embedded databases even in 2019. But it's not correctly implemented in either of them: the transaction is rolled back as soon as the client disconnects. According to the X/Open spec, when a database prepares a transaction, its data should be persistently stored and must be available to be committed later.

In H2 the XA code [is unmaintained](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2347#issuecomment-567457736).

If you want an XA-supporting database for your tests, you can use Postgres using the [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) project:

```java
@ClassRule
public static PostgreSQLContainer container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.1")
        .withCommand("postgres -c max_prepared_transactions=10");
```

Then create a datasource like this:

```java
PGXADataSource dataSource = new PGXADataSource();
dataSource.setURL(container.getJdbcUrl());
dataSource.setUser(container.getUsername());
dataSource.setPassword(container.getPassword());
dataSource.setDatabaseName(container.getDatabaseName());
```